# Onclick write to database whithout refreshing

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, flask

I've been working on a Flask application for a while.

Everything going pretty smooth because I was avoiding a problem. When writing to the database I always used a post ( that makes the page reloading ).

Not a big problem when posting forms etc.

Now I want a "i want help" button that makes a value true or false in the db.

Based on this value i would generate html that provides help.

But the button cannot make the page refresh. This is where i got stuck.

I only managed to get it working without writing to the db ( and storing it localy ).

Is there an obvious thing that i miss? or some Flask magic that gets it done.

The solution that I'm thinking about is posting to the db after leaving the page. Haven't got this working though.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This example uses [Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) to send some data to the [Flask back-end](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/quickstart/#the-request-object) with [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) and receive a response. It's very simple, but I marked the place where you'd handle the processing that you want the back-end to take care of after the user clicks your help button.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template_string, request


app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template_string('''
        <html>
            <head>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    $(document).ready(function() {
                        $('#send_data').on('click', function() {
                            $.ajax({
                                url: "{{ url_for('data_post') }}",
                                method: "POST",
                                data: {
                                    data: $('#data').val()
                                },
                                success: function(data) {
                                    $('#response').html(data);
                                }
                            });
                        });
                    });
                </script>
            </head>
            <body>
                <input type="text" name="" id="data">
                <button id="send_data">Send</button>
                <br />
                <p id="response"></p>
            </body>
        </html>
        ''')


@app.route('/data', methods=['POST'])
def data_post():
    # handle your database access, etc.
    return 'received'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

It's a simple index page with a textbox and button. Enter something into the textbox and click the button. You should see "received" on the page underneath the makeshift form, which is the echo from the back-end that the processing (in this example there isn't any) is done.

Comment: I didn't run your code, but the idea is pretty clear and usefull. 
Little question:
why would you say .data_post in the url for?

Comment: That's just the name of the second method: `def post_data():`, the one that accepts the HTTP POST data.

Comment: Sure thing, but I never use the dot .. :p

Comment: Ah, gotcha. The dot notation is for blueprints: `.method_name` references the current blueprint's method 'method_name'. In this example, it'd be better to exclude it. Good catch!

Answer (score 1):

I'm also working on a Flask app currently, if you don't want to reload the webpage, you'll have to make an AJAX call. This can be easily done via `jQuery.post()` function. Also, you might need to setup a new route in Flask, so as to provide the required data to which the post function will make a request. To disable auto form submission, you can use:

```
$('form').submit(false);
```

And for posting manually and receiving data from server, you can use:

```
<button ... onclick="submitForm()">Submit</button>
```

And submitForm():

```
function submitForm()
{
    $.post( url, { "data": "form-data" }).done(function (){...});
}
```

Hope this helps.